# Variable substitution in Pydev code templates

Tags: pydev

Pydev offers code templates when you create a new Python module. They include variable substitution such as `${my_variable}`. How are these variables supposed to be given values?

Answer (score 0):

Those "variables" are not user's variables.

Their whole list is available via button "Edit Variables...". This button appears when you edit a PyDev editor template (either creating a new one of modifying an old one). Their definitions are prefixed within PyDev. You should neither expect to define your own template variables nor expect to modify the definition of the already provided ones.

Comment: I can find no button labeled "Edit Variables". The only one I can find is labeled "Insert Variables" which is not the same thing. I am interested in the values of variables such as '${user}' that are specific to the environment that they are used in. They show up in the source code as the variable name and never take on a value. I am using Pydev version 7.5.

Comment: Gulp, you're right. Il failed typing the correct verb for the button. Insert is the correct one. You can't edit anything there... Sorry for this mistake (it was late here when I answered your question)

Comment: About the ${user} variable: it appears that it is filled with the account name you are logged in with. I can verify this only with Windows, and it works that way on my personal PC as well as on the company one. What is your environment?

Comment: I am running the latest release of Linux - Ubuntu, 20.04. Part of my problem is that none of the variables in a module template are getting values,

Comment: well, don't know why... Sorry about that. Things are fine with Windows, but this is of no help to you.